# Image gets saved to wroung folder on sdcard Android

Tags: android, android-sdcard, r.java-file

The code seems to work fine. The problem is that afterwards in my gallery I do not have an folder "myFolder" with my pics in it. Instead the pics get saved to `storage/sdcard0/DCIM/camera` and `myFolder` doesnt show up.
`myDirectory = final static String myDirectory = "myFolder"`.

```
private void createDirectoryAndSaveFile(Bitmap imageToSave, String fileName) {

    final File imageRoot = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), myDirectory);

    if (!imageRoot.exists()) {
        imageRoot.mkdirs();
    }

    File file = new File(imageRoot, fileName);

    try {
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        imageToSave.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: are you sure this method is getting called? either debug the app, or add some logs inside the method, ex: `Log.d("SAVE_IMAGE","calling createDirectoryAndSaveFile()...")` to make sure this method is getting called. check logcat if you can see this log line when image is saved

Comment: Yes I am sure. I debugged it (a lot :-) and even when I retrieve the Image I use myDirectory and it works flawless. Only in the gallery it is shown under storage/sdcard0/DCIM/camera

Comment: now myFolder showed up with 1 pic in it. whereas the 20 other pics savd with the same function are under storage/sdcard0/DCIM/camera